# How to add lines to file only if there aren't duplicates?

Tags: python, file, duplicates, set, append

I have this code in Python which adds a line to a given file. The problem is that i want to add this `blazegraph_address`  only if there isn't the same line already in the file. If there is, I don't need the address to be added to the file. The function code for this is below:

```
def write_to_address_file(blazegraph_address):
    address_path = open("./saved_info/saved_address.txt", "a")

    with open("./saved_info/saved_address.txt") as f:
        seen = set()
        seen.add(f.read())
        print("SEEN",seen)
        if blazegraph_address in seen:
            print("ADDRESS IN SET ALREADY")
        else:
            seen.add(blazegraph_address)
            address_path.write("\n"+str(blazegraph_address))
```

The problem is that the set populates with the file contents even though there are duplicates. How to only add to the file if the address is not in the file already?

Answer (score 0):

Your code read the entire file, not line by line.
For this, you need to use create your set with the lines:

Modify:

```
seen = set()
seen.add(f.read())
```

With:

```
seen = set(f.read().split('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def write_to_address_file(blazegraph_address):
    address_path = open("./saved_info/saved_address.txt", "a")

    with open("./saved_info/saved_address.txt", "r") as msg:
        data = msg.read().splitlines()

    if blazegraph_address in data:
        print("ADDRESS IN SET ALREADY")
    else:
        address_path.write("\n"+str(blazegraph_address))
```